# Get possible paths with BPMN.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpmn, bpmn.io

I'm using BPMN.io and I need to get the possible paths for a process or a subprocess. I mean, with a process Id I need the elements of that diagram.

I have to paint the tasks and sequence flows that have been reached. I have that information, but I need the path in order to check if the whole process or subprocess have been reached.

Is there any way to get that? The only way I see is looking over all the items and saving the ids of the elements. But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Can you please add the process XML / JSON to your question? Can you also please be a little bit more specific on what you try to achieve? What do you exactly mean by "whole process or subprocess have been reached" ?

Comment: I have a big XML with multiple process and subprocess. As it is a big bpmn I have some suprocess colapsed, you can see the subprocess element but you have to click to see that subprocess in detail. So I need to show in the subprocess element if the whole suprocess is completed. To get that, I need to know all possible paths  in the subprocess in order to check if that elements has been reached or finished.

Comment: Ok, are you using [bpmn-moddle](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-moddle)?